# Comparing 2 columns in same database table

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a column in a database table called "ChangePolicy" it always holds a number, and it represents the number of months.  I also have a column in the same table called "LastChanged" and represents the date the item was last changed.  I'm struggling with the query needed to return all items that are due to be changed based on the LastChanged date and the ChangePolicy.  Meaning: If the ChangePolicy is 3 months, I need to return all items that are 3 months or longer since the LastChanged date.

I have the following but it's not providing the desired results.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE lastchanged <= dateadd(month, +3, getdate())
```

Comment: Well, I'm not taking into account the ChangePolicy column in my query.

Comment: Why aren't you using `ChangePolicy` in your query?

Comment: @TabAlleman I wasn't sure how to implement correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding correctly, here's one option:

```
select * 
from yourtable
where lastchanged <= dateadd(month, -1 * changepolicy, getdate())
```

- [Online Demo](http://rextester.com/OWITJ20040)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, worked just as I had hoped.